# Remove a substring if repeated more than once sequentially

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

I have  a list

```
my_list=['Hello jose','jjjj','jack signal','jjjjjj']
```

I tried

```
[i.replace('j','') for i in my_list]
```

my output:

```
['hello ose', '', 'ackpot', '']
```

my expected output:

```
['Hello jose','','jackpot','']
```

How to remove a substring 'j' if it is repeated right next to another?

Comment: `[i.replace('jj', '') for i in my_list]`?  Not sure if that produces the result you want if you have an odd number of `j`s though.

Comment: Do you want to replace any repeated character or only 'j'?

Comment: @DYZ I guess it is only `j`; `"hello"` is surviving in the example.

Comment: @j1-lee I'd rather hear the interpretation from the OP.

Comment: any repeated character

Comment: if  the string contains xxx, it has to remove it

Comment: @DYZ You were right!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex:

```py
import re

my_list=['Hello jose','jjjj','jack signal','jjjjjj']

output = [re.sub(r"(.)\1+", "", s) for s in my_list]
print(output) # ['Heo jose', '', 'jack signal', '']
```

Comment: For the string to substitute, you can also use `r"jj+"`

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression that you are looking for is below:

```
output = [re.sub(r"(.)\1{2,}", "", s) for s in my_list]
```

It finds and replaces any character `"(.)"` followed by two or more copies of the same `"\1{2,}"`. `"\1"` is a reference to the match in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to check for consecutive repetition of `'j'` and if not found append it to a temporary string and replace it in `my_list`, like thi...

```py
my_list=['Hello jose','jjjj','jack signal','jjjjjj']

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    temp_str, my_str, flag = "", my_list[i], 0

    for j in range(len(my_str)-1):
        if (my_str[j] == "j") and (my_str[j] == my_str[j+1]):
            continue
        else:
            temp_str += my_str[j]; flag=1
    else:
        temp_str += my_str[-1] if flag else ""

    my_list[i] = temp_str

print(my_list)
```

Output:-

```
['Hello jose', '', 'jack signal', '']
```